# No Dependency Injection and missing EclispeContext in Plugin

Tags: eclipse, dependency-injection, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, e4

I have written an eclipse product, based on Eclipse Neon, which contains a self written plugin. Now I changed the platform to Eclipse 2019-06. Since then I get an InjectionException at the integratetd plugin.

I've debugged the code and found out, that the injection of this Plugin doesn't work any more and the EclipseContext is always null. I also tried to create the Objects with the @Creatable Annotation.

Do I have to transport the context from one plugin to another? In my opinion this isn't necessesary. So, had someone else this problem and has solved it?

Comment: What injection exception? Eclipse uses injection extensively and it works fine in 2019-06, show us what you doing.

Comment: I have solved it already. It was another plugin which has destroyed the context. I do not need it and have removed it. Now everything works fine now.